# App won't launch on device or simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

So... this is beyond strange.

I had an app that was running perfectly fine in simulator and on device. I've actually already submitted the app and it is for sale in the App Store.

Today I went back in and made a few changes for an update.
The app now will not load on my device and it won't load in the simulator.

In the simulator it says "Attaching to app_name" (it lists the actual app name) and it stays on this process of "Attaching" indefinitely, while the Simulator screen is entirely black.

When running the app on the device it says "Build Succeeded", then "Finished running app_name" without anything ever showing up on the device.

I restarted XCode and tried restarting my computer, but still no luck...
Other apps do work, but not this one.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just started a brand new project, copied over all the assets and code, tried running and STILL the same thing happened. I thought for sure creating the project anew would work...

FINAL EDIT: After running "Clean", deleting the DerivedData folder, and restarting my computer a SECOND time, the new project (with all assets copied over) is now working. The original project still does not work. So I am not sure what caused the issue and what fixed the issue, but for me at least I can now move on. What do I do with this thread? Can it just be deleted? Thanks everyone who chimed in to try and help!

Comment: Have you switched to XCode 4? I've been having this issue since switching, and it just seems to be happening randomly for some reason.

Comment: Yes - I switched to XCode 4 and have done work on several apps (including this one) without any problems IN XCode 4 until today.  =/

Comment: Can you make a new blank project and run that? (without copying your old stuff over)

Comment: I could run a new blank project and several other apps, just couldn't run this particular app that was giving me issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the options move the DerivedData into your project directory. Whenever I have problems with xcode4 I just quit it and delete this directory. It contains the builds and caches of the background compiles that xcode4 does.

Deleting this folder usually fixes all problems I get.

Comment: I kept my fingers crossed as I deleted the project's DerivedData directory both in /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData as well as in the project directory... still does not run.   =(

Comment: After restarting my computer for a second time since encountering this issue (first time since deleting the DerivedData directory), the new project I created and copied all assets over to now works! YES! I don't know if deleting this folder is the reason it is now working but maybe it helped. The original project still won't load in the Simulator, but I've recreated it and am moving on!

Comment: for simulator problem,I deleted derived data as well rested simulator.

Comment: I was able to fix it by deleting the derived data, resetting the simulator and shutting it (the simulator app) down. I also found that I got into the issue when trying to copy over a folder called Resources into the bundle. 2 times I got into this problem trying to do that. Third time, I renamed that folder to just Res and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Tried above options but didn't work for me.

Finally, Just Resetting Simulator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. In Xcode 4: Product menu >> Clean.

Comment: Thanks - Clean has saved me many times before - but did not help here.

Comment: Clean *and* deleted from device?

Comment: Yes, clean and deleted. The fact that it doesn't work on the device OR the simulator is the strange part. I have never had an app that wouldn't run in the simulator without offering any type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this one.you can quit the simulator and run the project again.This works for me

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different solutions people suggest for this:

- Do a clean
- Reset simulator
- Do a 'clean build folder' (hold down option key when selecting clean)
- Remove ~/Library/Developer Tools/Xcode/Derived Data/YourProject*
- Remove your 'xcuserdata' directory inside your .xcodeproj directory

I just spent an hour trying different combinations of the items above, doing all of them, ... nothing worked. My app would either 1) Immediately start and quit before launch screen would show up, or 2) Hang at launch screen. The simulator took forever to reset, sometimes wouldn't respond to a Quit, ... Just really odd stuff going on.

*This* solved my problem: **Reboot machine**.

(It blows my mind this had to be done on Mac OS, but it worked. This may have something to do with upgrading to XCode 4.6 and not rebooting since then, I'm not sure... But I'm back running again)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all posts here without success. Then I found something that worked for me:

I had a ~3000 resources folder in my Xcode Project.
At first I had them as "folder reference", which made XCode unable to launch the app.
When I switched them to be a "group" in the project, the error was gone.
I still needed to restart Xcode and the Simulator and rebuild, but it worked.